# How to implement bold unbold functionality with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, text-formatting

I am trying to implement some client side text formatting functionality.  Just like any other editor does.  Basically when the user selects text and clicks on bold, it should bold the text and when the same text is selected again, and bold is clicked.  It should unbold it.  I can achieve this functionality by simply using jQuery wrap and unwrap function.

The problem I am having is that if user selects text which is a substring of something that already has bold tags around it. For example   `<b>Some text "I am the selection" some text</b>`  In this case clicking on the button should unbold  "I am the selection" and keep the text around it bold. The project is also build on angularJS.

Questions:
What is the best way of solving this?  (My last option is to process text as a string and do a manual replace on it which I am really trying to avoid)
Is there an angular way of doing?
Is there a good plugin just for this functionality (I do not want a full toolbar because I have already created my own to go with the project, I just want the functionality)

http://plnkr.co/edit/KmVBjOeUps302NrdV89k?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var myObj = $('#highlight');
        myObj.html( myObj.html().replace(getSelectedText(),
            '<b>'+getSelectedText()+'</b>')
        );
    });
});
```

Where #highlight is the id of the paragraph you want to select from. This would just bold the area, I'll leave the unbolding to you ;)